# How can I mount a mojolicious app with PSGI?

Tags: perl, mojolicious, plack

I would like to mount a [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious) app with others using [plackup](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Plack/script/plackup) or [starman](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Starman/script/starman).

The docs here [here](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Plack-middleware) describe how to use a single application, but not how I could have a Mojolicious app coexist with other [Catalyst](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst)- or [Dancer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer)-based ones behind the same plackup/starman instance.

I'd like to do something like

```
  builder {
      enable 'Debug';
      enable 'Session', store => 'File';

      mount '/prospero' => Prospero->psgi_app;

      mount "/vizela" => 'Vizela/vizela.pl'

      #-------------------------------------------------
      # standard app
      #-------------------------------------------------
      mount '/', $app;
  };
```

where Prospero is a catalyst app, and vizela is a mojolicious one, but there's no hint in this direction in the documentation - or maybe I haven't found it.

And advice on how to get this done?

Unfortunately deploying behind nginx or apache is not an option, and different servers aren't either, because of the need to have one source for all data (cross-server limitations).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK all a psgi app consists of is a coderef.

So, it's just the
    app->start
bit you want.

It's almost demonstrated here: http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Plack-middleware